# "Translating" procedural for loops into Terraform

Tags: terraform, logic

[Terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/intro) is a leading infastrucutre-as-code platform. Terraform has many of the core features of traditional programming languages, such as conditions and function calls. However, according to [this tutorial](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9) it lacks traditional for-loops and instead has a menergie of different iteration constructs.

**How do you translate more complex programs into Terraform's system of iterators**? Consider this simplified [slime-mold-like](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10462-021-10100-5) algorithm that creates a sparse network (Terraform has tools to design networks but there are always edge-cases where custom algorithms work better):

```
#Python code (TODO: use numba for performance)
weights = np.random.random([N,N]) # N VPCs
for _ in range(16*N*N): # Enough steps to converge?
   i,j = simulate_packet() # We have a model of who is likely to send packets to whom.
   path = weighted_shortest_path(1.0/weights, i, j) # Favor busy routes with a strong pre-existing connection of "protoplasm".
   for k in range(len(path)-1):
     weights[path[k], path[k+1]] += 0.025 # Reinforce said path in a positive feedback loop.
peering_pairs = ... # Make VPC/Vnet peers if they high enough weights, ensuring a connected graph.
```

The above Python code is straightforward to translate to other "procedural" languages such as C++ and Ruby. "Functional" languages such as Haskell and (idiomatic) Clojure don't have for/while loops and require writing the body of the loop as a function call and calling the function with [tail recursion](https://jxs.me/2010/06/28/tail-recursion-haskell/).

I don't know how to rewrite this code in Terraform. Am I overlooking a fairly easy way to "translate" this loop? Or is Terraform not used when there is a need to do more complex programming logic?

Comment: Terraform isn't really designed for this sort of general computation; typically someone with this requirement would calculate the necessary data once outside of Terraform and then encode its _result_ as data in the Terraform configuration. But if you would like to attempt it, one approach that might help is to try to rewrite your algorithm using Python list and map comprehensions first. Terraform's [`for` expressions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) are equivalent, so it should be easier to translate from that starting point.

Comment: @MartinAtkins: This was the feeling I got. Terraform is like regexp or C++ templates: it does what it does *really well* but please don't program in it. Regexp is called from Python/C/Ruby/etc; if the complexity grows and your regexp is no longer sufficient you can fall back on the enclosing language. I would use Python as the "enclosing language" in a Terraform-heavy workflow (which would mean the Python scripts must have access to env variables and can run at deployment time, etc).